# How do I connect my subscription office 365 business basic to Editor ADSI?

Tags: office365, ms-office, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I'm new to office 365. I bought a basic business subscription (mydomain.onmicrosoft.com | mydomain.com) and did a migration on Exchange. It migrated fine, however there were a few things I didn't want to be migrated, so I deleted the migrated emails and tried a new migration.

When I did that I got the following error: UserAlreadyBeingMigratedException.

Apparently I wrongly eliminated the migration and left an orphan request for the mailbox, finding out a lot there I managed to connect to powershell (without understanding how it really works).

Reviewing the microsoft guide,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4502865/cannot-move-mailboxes-from-on-premises-to-exchange-online

Eliminate the migration, eliminate the end of migration, it did not work and Microsoft recommends me to apply the following configuration:

1. Open Active Directory Users and Computers in Domain Controller (DC) server.
2. Modified attribute msExchMailboxMoveRemoteHostName

This tutorial also details what I should do.
http://pipe2text.com/?page_id=2849

I am clear about what I must do, connect my office365 or exchange onlie account to ADSI Edit, and correct the parameters from there, the problem is that I do not know how to connect my account or domain. I have windos 10 and I have the tool but I don't know what to place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow the following steps

1. Open Active Directory Users and Computers in Domain Controller (DC) server.
2. Locate the affected user, click View, select the Advanced Features check box, and then open the Attribute Editor tab.
3. Look for msExchMailboxMove* attributes, and check whether any value is set for that user.

If the move request was successfully removed from Exchange Online (that is, you don't find it by running Get-MoveRequest in Exchange Online PowerShell) but the msExchMailboxMoveRemoteHostName attribute is set, this suggests that the move reference was not cleared up correctly from on-premises Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). In this scenario, you have an orphaned move request for that user.

Another example for an orphaned local move request for a primary or archived mailbox would be if there's no move request on-premises for it, but there are attributes set, such as the following:

**msExchMailboxMoveSourceMDBLink**
**msExchMailboxMoveTargetMDBLink**
**msExchMailboxMoveSourceArchiveMDBLink**
**msExchMailboxMoveTargetArchiveMDBLink**

4. Manually clear the value in Azure AD, and then create another move request in Exchange Online for that user.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4502865/cannot-move-mailboxes-from-on-premises-to-exchange-online

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: I know what I have to do, the problem is that I don't know how to connect to Azure AD with my account in Office 365.  I shared a screenshot, could you see it? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to help you to get it done using Active Directory console and not ADSI Edit. I am still not able to understand your requirement completely. The above solution will help to resolve the issue mentioned in the error (UserAlreadyBeingMigratedException.). Could you please explain a bit more on what you are trying to do above that
Thanks,

Comment: I have an office 365 account, with my domain (mydomain.com | mydomain.onmicrosoft.com). I want to connect as Microsoft tells me in the tutorial (Open Active Directory Users and Computers), but I am not clear what I should connect to and how I should do it. To be honest, I'm new to exchange, office365, powershell and don't know anything about windows server. So I do not know how to connect, from where to connect and where to connect.

Thanks, again

Comment: As you mentioned in your post, you have migrated mailboxes to Exchange server. So, you should have on-premises windows servers available as I believe. So, go to your Exchange or Domain Controller and login as domain\Administrator. Open Run Menu (Windows Key + R) and Type DSA.MSC and enter. This will Open Active Directory console. Remaining steps are mentioned in my first post as the reply to your question. Those steps will help to resolve the issue. I can help on this further, if you have still some questions